# Using constant as keys in ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Assuming I have 2 strings constants

```
KEY1 = "Hello"
KEY2 = "World"
```

I would like to create a hash using these constants as key values.

Trying something like this:

```
stories = {
  KEY1: { title: "The epic run" },
  KEY2: { title: "The epic fail" }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work

```
stories.inspect
#=> "{:KEY1=>{:title=>\"The epic run\"}, :KEY2=>{:title=>\"The epic fail\"}}"
```

and `stories[KEY1]` obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`KEY1:` is the syntax sugar to `:KEY1 =>`, so you're actually having ***symbol*** as key, not constant.

To have actual object as a key, use hash rocket notation:

```
stories = {
  KEY1 => { title: "The epic run" },
  KEY2 => { title: "The epic fail" }
}
stories[KEY1]
#=> {:title=>"The epic run"}
```